# Javascript Countdown for every 3 Seconds

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

This is my first post on this forum,
I shearched all around the web for a javascript countdown that change every 3 ( and not 1 second ) 
Exemple : script show "30" after 3 second the script will show "29" 
Can you help me on this ?
Thanks :D

Comment: Are you serious about your problem?

Comment: Post your script and we'll help modify.

Comment: Go and learn how to code and then come back and we can help you if you have any problems. Otherwise hire a developer.

Comment: @Andy I am not agree with you. As that question is still about programming although very easy. And where is scale that exactly determines whether I should go and learn or ask question?

Comment: Because the OP has obviously been able to find counters, but not one to his/her _exact_ specification. They're unable to extrapolate from those examples. They have no programming knowledge and expect to come here and get us to do the work. And that's not what SO is for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) function to execute a certain code every x miliseconds, e.g. every 3000ms = 3s. The callback function you pass to `setInterval` then gets executed every x ms. In your case you have to get a reference to the DOM object holding the value, decrement it and pass it back into the DOM element. You also have to stop the timer when it's done. Example:

```js
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("timerCounter");
  var val = parseInt(elem.innerHTML);

  if (val === 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    return;
  }

  val--;

  elem.innerHTML = val;
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="timerCounter">30</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although stackoverflow is not write-code-for-you service I will give you starting point. For that you can use [setInverval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp):

```
var counter = 30;

setInterval(function () { 
    console.log(--counter); 
}, 3000);
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/monua83m/1/)

Comment: Note. I deliberately didn't stop that counter as it was unclear from question when it should stop or should it stop at all =)

Answer (score -1):

Notes

- use [window.setInterval(callback, interval)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)
- Don't forgot to clear the interval when you've finished with window.clearInterval(reference)

```js
var counter = 30;
var output = document.getElementById('foo');
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (counter == 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  output.innerHTML = "Counter = " + counter;
  counter--;
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="foo">
</div>
```